# Binary search through string tuple in list

Tags: python, list, tuples, binary-search

I'm trying to do a binary search through a list of tuples, when I give a inputq = "BB", it is not show a correct search.

This is my data:

```
alldtata = [('BA', 'Bosnia and Herzegovina', 44.0, 18.0), ('BB', 'Barbados', 13.17, -59.53), ('BD', 'Bangladesh', 24.0, 90.0), ('BE', 'Belgium', 50.83, 4.0), ('BF', 'Burkina Faso', 13.0, -2.0), ('BG', 'Bulgaria', 43.0, 25.0), ('BH', 'Bahrain', 26.0, 50.55), ('BJ', 'Benin', 9.5, 2.25), ('BM', 'Bermuda', 32.33, -64.75), ('BN', 'Brunei Darussalam', 4.5, 114.67)]
```

This my code:

```
def binarySearch(arr, x):
    l = 0
    r = len(arr)-1
    while (l <= r):
        m = l + ((r - l) // 2)
        res = (x == arr[m])
        if (res == 0):
            return m - 1
        if (res > 0):
            l = m + 1
        else:
            r = m - 1
 
    return -1

inputq = "BB"
showall = binarySearch(alldtata, inputq)
for indexcodename, value in enumerate(alldtata):
    if indexcodename == showall:
        print(value)
```

when I give inputq = "BB" the output it always show like this: ('BF', 'Burkina Faso', 13.0, -2.0)

I would like to show my output like this when I give inputq = "BB"

('BB', 'Barbados', 13.17, -59.53)
how to do that?

Comment: You want only with binary searh? Normal search alos works?

Comment: your `res` is actually a boolean (True/False), so you can't compare it with 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two main problems with your algorithm.  First, as @gog points out, you are calculating `res` as a boolean, but then are comparing it with integers.  The other thing is that you are comparing the term `arr[m]` to the target, as though that term refers to the equivalent value in the data structure. It does not.  Rather, it refers to the entire tuple.  What you want instead is `arr[m][0]`.

Fixing those two issues, and maybe a few small issues, here's a new version of your code that seems to correctly find any value in the array:

```
def binarySearch(arr, x):
    l = 0
    r = len(arr)-1
    while l <= r:
        m = l + ((r - l) // 2)
        mm = arr[m][0]
        if x == mm:
            return m
        if x > mm:
            l = m + 1
        else:
            r = m - 1
    return -1
```

Result (when the original function is replaced with this new version in the original code):

```
('BB', 'Barbados', 13.17, -59.53)
```

Comment: I found one other problem.  You were initially setting `r = len(arr)`.  That should be `r = len(arr)-1`.  I changed it above.

Comment: @KellyBundy.- I guess you're my QA department.  How about now?

Comment: @KellyBundy.- Huh?  I added a '-1'.

Comment: Wasn't there yet. Your edit came [21 seconds *after* your comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ML9om.png). Now that's fixed, yes

Comment: whew...good thing we got that straight.

Comment: Or did you actually edit before posting the comment, and SO just for some reason delayed the edit? I've had that feeling sometimes before, when people commented that they had changed something but SO showed that the change happened later.

Comment: Yeah, must have been something like that